# Query/filter binned documents in a terms query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I've got some data that share a property, lets say I've got these documents:

```
{
   session: "session-1",
   status: "New",
},
{
  session: "session-1",
  title: "My session",
},
{
   session: "session-1",
   message: "hi there",
},
{
   session: "session-2",
   status: "Closed",
},
{
   session: "session-2",
   message: "hi!",
},
```

If I do an aggregation:

```
body: {
  aggs: {
    sessions: {
      field: "session",
    },
  },
},
```

I get two buckets, with 3 and 2 documents in:

```
"aggregations": {
    "sessions": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,   
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,           
      "buckets": [                        
        {
          "key": "session-1",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "session-2",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

Can I run a filter or query on the buckets in some way?

```
body: {
  aggs: {
    sessions: {
      field: "session",
    },
    aggs: {
      filter_docs: { bool: must [{ match: { message: "hi" } }, { match: { status: "New" } }],
    }
  },
},
```

I know I can can apply a `query` over all the documents, but I want to be able to do more complex filters in the sub documents (i.e. filter out buckets that contain BOTH a `message: hi` and a `status: New`)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no document in the example shown above that contains BOTH a `message: hi` and a `status: New`.

Adding a working example for filtering the documents that contain both `message: Hi` and `session: session-1` using [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html).

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filtererd": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "message": "hi"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "session.keyword": "session-1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_filter": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"aggregations": {
    "filtererd": {
      "doc_count": 1,
      "top_filter": {
        "hits": {
          "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
          },
          "max_score": 1.0,
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "66714173",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_id": "3",
              "_score": 1.0,
              "_source": {
                "session": "session-1",
                "message": "hi there"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**If you want to filter the result of terms aggregation**

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "session"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filtererd": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "message": "hi"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result will be**

```
"aggregations": {
    "genres": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "session-1",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "filtererd": {
            "doc_count": 1             // note this
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "session-2",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "filtererd": {
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: @Joe did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)